# GuildEmojis and UnicodeEmojis are not working well together

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, emoji

I am searching for something that unicode emojis and custom emojis have in common together.
Lets say I have a JSON file

```
{
     "emojis": ["something1", "something2", "something3"]
}
```

My discord.js bot should now compare lets say a messageReactionAdd-event's emoji to the elements of this array. Lets say if the emoji matches one of the somethings, console.log("trigger") should happen. However the code is not important. I can't find anything I can compare what both Custom Emojis and Unicode Emojis have in common. Like a custom emoji has an ID, a unicode doesn't, therefore it has an "picture", like , a custom emoji doesn't. Does someone has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't understand your issue. Could you please try to reformulate ?

Comment: Actually, unicode emojis also have a "code" type thingy. 

`console.log(''.length)//2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store both unicode emojis and custom emoji IDs?

**emojis.json**

```
{
  "emojis": ["", "", "", "396548322053062656", "266241948824764416"];
}
```

**bot.js**

```js
const emojis = require('emojis.json').emojis;

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) || emojis.includes(reaction.emoji.id)) {
    console.log('Found emoji.');
  } else {
    console.log('Could not find emoji.');
  }
});
```

Comment: however when I console.log(emoji.id), my custom emoijis ID's are displayed, but for unicodes it says "null"

Comment: or could you please tell me the emoji id of ✅

Comment: emit the event with that emoji and log its ID. As stated in the answer, discord.js will return the ID for you.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide a different approach.